# Tekton: How delete successful pipelineruns?

Tags: kubernetes, pipeline, cicd, tekton

My aspired tekton usecase is simple:

- successful pipelineruns should be removed after x days
- failed pipelineruns shouldn't be removed automatically.

I plan to do the cleanup in an initial cleanup-task. That seems better to me than annotation- or cronjob-approaches. As long as nothing new is built, nothing has to be deleted.

Direct approaches:

- **Failed**: `tkn delete` doesn't seem very helpful because it doesn't discriminate between successful or not.
- **Failed**: `oc delete --field-selector ...` doesn't contain the well hidden but highly expressive field `status.conditions[0].type==Succeeded`

Indirect approaches (first filtering a list of podnames and then delete them - not elegant at all):

- **Failed**: Filtering output with `-o=jsonpath...` seems costly and the condition-array seems to break the statement, so that (why ever?!) everything is returned... not viable
- My last attempt is `tkn pipelineruns list --show-managed-fields` and parse this with sed/awk... which is gross... but at least it does what I want it to do... and quite efficiently at that. But it might result as brittle when the design of the output is going to change in future releases...

Do you have any better more elegant approaches?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `tkn pipelineruns list --show-managed-fields -n e-dodo-tmgr --label tekton.dev/pipeline=deploy-pipeline | awk '$6~/Succeeded/ && $3~/day|week|month/ {print $1}'` delivers the desired list of pipelineruns to delete... well done, awk :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, I paste here the kubectl/oc native command for those of us who do not have the tkn cli. Replace `target-namespace` as needed.

Delete failed pipelineruns:

```
kubectl -n target-namespace delete pipelinerun $(kubectl -n target-namespace get pipelinerun -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.status.conditions[*].status=="False")]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}')
```

Delete successful pipelineruns:

```
kubectl -n target-namespace delete pipelinerun $(kubectl -n target-namespace get pipelinerun -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.status.conditions[*].status=="True")]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Until a better solution is there, I'll post my current solution (and its drawbacks):

Our cleanup-task is now built around the following solution, evaluating the table returned by `tkn pipelineruns list`:

```
tkn pipelineruns list --show-managed-fields -n e-dodo-tmgr --label tekton.dev/pipeline=deploy-pipeline | awk '$6~/Succeeded/ && $3~/day|week|month/ {print $1}'
```

Advantages:

- It does what it should without extensive calls or additional calculation.

Disadvantages:

- Time is limited to "older than an hour / a day / a week ..." But that's acceptable, since only successful builds are concerned.
- I guess the design is quite brittle, because with changes in the tkn-Client the format of the table might change which implies that awk will pick the wrong columns, or similar pattern-probs.

All in all I hope the solution will hold until there are some more helpful client-features that make the desired info directly filterable. Actually I'd hope for something like `tkn pipelineruns delete --state successful --period P1D`.
The notation for the time period is from ISO8601.